# how to login to multiple website accounts concurrently with Python

Tags: python, cookies, concurrency, authentication, urllib2

I am using urllib2 and [HTTPCookieProcessor](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#httpcookieprocessor-objects) to login to a website. I want to login to multiple accounts concurrently and store the cookies to be reused later.

Can you recommend an approach or library to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP clarified that this is not a concurrency issue.  With sequential processing in mind, this is much simpler.  I once used something like the following to update a bunch of SIP phone base stations (they had a web front-end which you could use to upload VCard files for the phone book).  Note that I just cut away some crap and renamed this and that in this hacky script, I did *not* test it at all.  Its sole purpose is to give the OP an idea on how he could deal with this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from optparse import OptionParser
import sys
from mechanize import Browser, CookieJar, Request, urlopen


accounts = [
    {'ipaddr': '127.0.0.1', 'user': 'joe', 'pass': 'foobar'},
    ]


class WebsiteAccount(object):

    def __init__(self, ipaddr, username, password, browser):
        self.ipaddr = ipaddr
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.browser = browser
        self.cookiejar = CookieJar()
        self.browser.set_cookiejar(self.cookiejar)

    def login(self):
        self.browser.open('http://'+self.ipaddr+'/login.html')
        self.browser.select_form(name='loginform')
        self.browser.form.set_value(self.username, name='username')
        self.browser.form.set_value(self.password, name='password')
        resp = self.browser.submit()
        print 'Logging into account %s@%s ...' % (self.username, self.ipaddr),
        if resp.geturl().endswith('/login.html'):
            print 'FAILED!'
            sys.exit(1)
        print ' OK'

    def logout(self):
        print ('Logging out from account %s@%s...' % (self.username, self.ipaddr),
        self.browser.open('http://'+self.ipaddr+'/logout.html')
        self.browser.close()
        print 'OK'


def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-d', '--debug', action='store_true', dest='debug', default=False)
    parser.add_option('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', dest='verbose', default=False)
    (opts, args) = parser.parse_args()
    for account in accounts:
        browser = Browser()
        browser.set_handle_referer(True)
        browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
        browser.set_handle_robots(False)
        bs = WebsiteAccount(account['ipaddr'],
                            account['user'],
                            account['pass'],
                            browser)
        # DEBUG
        if opts.debug == True:
            browser.set_debug_redirects(True)
            browser.set_debug_responses(True)
            browser.set_debug_http(True)
        bs.login()
        try:
            # ... do some stuff
            # save cookies here?  
            pass
        finally:
            # you shouldn't use this if you are interested in the login cookies
            bs.logout()


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Note: using sys.exit like this is gross, use exceptions instead.

Comment: yeah I guess something like that with separate cookie jars is what I need to keep the sessions independant

Answer (score 1):

How to achieve this really depends on you needs: what kind of login is it? Digest authentication?  Is it a web form?  Is JavaScript involved (you're pretty much screwed if this is the case)?  A library like [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) can help you a lot with such stuff: handling of forms, redirection, authentication, cookies... However, you'd have to take care of concurrency yourself by spawning threads/processes.

Another approach that works beautifully for concurrency is using [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/9.0.0/api/twisted.web.http.HTTPClient.html). With that solution however you'd have to handle redirection and cookies etc. yourself -- although you might be able to reuse parts of e.g. mechanize.

Comment: it's simple form based with cookies and I have it working for single login. Threading isn't the problem so much as handling multiple cookie sessions.

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with concurrency (you should remove that tag). In this case you could simply instantiate a new cookiejar class for every account.

Comment: I will be accessing multiple accounts concurrently so it is related to concurrency. What I meant is threading is not the difficult part.